# Get asp.net radiobuttonlist selected value in code behind when using jQuery buttonset

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist, jquery-ui-button

I am using the jQueryUI buttonset on an ASP.NET radiobuttonlist. I need to get the selected value in server-side code when the page posts back. If I don't apply the jQuery buttonset, this is of course easy enough - just grab "SelectedValue". However, when I do apply jQuery buttonset, the selected value does not appear to be available on postback any longer. Is there any way around this, or do I need to get the selected value on clientside, and then pass it back myself?

```
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList0" CssClass="ratingButtons" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Option1" Value="1"/>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Option2" Value="2" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Option" Value="3" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Option4" Value="4" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>

  $(function () {
      $(".ratingButtons").buttonset();
      $(".ratingButtons").click(function () { return false; });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line:

$(".ratingButtons").click(function () { return false; });